# jQuery slick (carousel) plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use this jQuery plugin ( http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ ) to a carousel. I tried many different plugins, but I always face some kind of error. So, I'm sticking with this until I figure out whats wrong.

Here is my HTML head:

```
<head>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src='http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js'></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.
        <script type=" text/javascript " src="slick/slick.min.js "></script>
        <script type="text/javascript " src='/js/carousel.js'></script>
</head>
```

When I tried it, I got an 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' at line to of my JS where I call the function 'slick'. Here it where I call it:

```
<div class="slider single-items"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

And here is my carousel.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.single-item').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting `$('.single-item')`, but your markup has elements with class `single-items` (with a "s" at the end). Assuming this pasted code is correct, your jQuery should be changed to `$('.single-items')`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.single-items').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N6wfG/

Comment: The path is right, I placed an alert at the slick.min.js, and its alerting but the problem persists.

Comment: You are selecting `$('.single-item')`, but your markup has elements with class `single-items` (with a "s" at the end). Assuming this pasted code is correct, your jQuery should be changed to `$('.single-items').slick`.

Comment: No, its not it. I corrected it, but error persists.

Comment: Well, it does work with the above modification, as can be seen in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N6wfG/ Then the error is somewhere else. Post more code if you want.

Comment: I found the problem,  the html page was loading two different jquery files, I was not aware of that. Found that reading all files loaded with chrome developer tools. The second one was an older version, not supported by slick plugin. I removed the older version, and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8):

I had similar problem, but in my case issue was following:

I had installed slick by `bower install slick` instead `bower install slick.js` which caused that I had totally different library included in my dependecies.

Comment: Thank you for this — I would never have caught this on my own.

Comment: Oh man I did the same thing and it was driving me batty. Thanks for the tip!